# SOQL nested query ContentVersion, ContentDocument, ContentDocumentLink

Tags: soql, contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink, subquery

I am trying to access ContentVersion, ContentDocument, ContentDocumentLink
to achieve a count of each contentversion per object.
[The relationships between the objects](https://driveconnect.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/content-document-data-model.png)

I activated QueryAll Document, and this gets me the count per ContendDocument for each objects :

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) counter, LinkedEntity.type
FROM ContentDocumentLink
GROUP BY LinkedEntity.type
```

But now given that I want to know the count of Id for each ContentVersion I am lost on how to query, given that a subquery should be like this for example :

```
SELECT Id, Title,
    (SELECT Id FROM ContentVersions),
    (SELECT Id, LinkedEntity.Type FROM ContentDocumentLinks)
FROM ContentDocument
```

which get me all the information, I have the contentVersions and the Object linked to it, but I cannot group to have a count.

Could a SOQL master help me here?

Thanks

Comment: Are you open to or have tried using Apex for the count part?

Comment: Hi Art, Are you exploring the data?  Or is there some other process that will consume the data?  As aryashah2k suggests, there's a lot of object oriented stuff you can do with Apex when you consume SOQL results with related objects.  Maybe you could describe where you're headed.